# Pandas matplotlib plotting, irregularities in time series labels between bar graph and line graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, graph

When creating bar graphs and line graphs using matplotlib via pandas I've come across some inconsistent behaviour. For example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from pandas_datareader import data

test_df = data.get_data_yahoo('AAPL', start='2015-10-01')
test_df['Adj Close'].plot()
```

Plots as expected with sensible x axis labels:

[image]

However if you then try to plot something from the same dataframe as a bar graph:

```
test_df['Volume'].plot(kind='bar')
```

[image]

The x axis tick labels are no longer automatically sensible.

Is this intended behaviour of pandas/matplotlib? And how can one easily rectify the x axis tick labels on bar graphs to be similar to the one in the line graph above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could tell matplotlib to show every Nth label:

```
# show every Nth label
locs, labels = plt.xticks()
N = 10
plt.xticks(locs[::N], test_df.index[::N].strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
```

---

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from pandas_datareader import data

test_df = data.get_data_yahoo('AAPL', start='2015-10-01')
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=2)
test_df['Adj Close'].plot(ax=ax[0])
test_df['Volume'].plot(kind='bar', ax=ax[1])

# show every Nth label
locs, labels = plt.xticks()
N = 10
plt.xticks(locs[::N], test_df.index[::N].strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))

# autorotate the xlabels
fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

yields
[image]

---

Another option is to use matplotlib directly:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from pandas_datareader import data
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

df = data.get_data_yahoo('AAPL', start='2015-10-01')
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=2, sharex=True)

ax[0].plot(df.index, df['Adj Close'])
ax[0].set_ylabel('price per share')

ax[1].bar(df.index, df['Volume']/10**6)
ax[1].xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator(bymonthday=-1))
xfmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%B %d, %Y')
ax[1].xaxis.set_major_formatter(xfmt)
ax[1].set_ylabel('Volume (millions)')

# autorotate the xlabels
fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, in addition would it be possibly to just plot month, year on the x axis (like October, 2015), and how would you make the y axis human readable?

Comment: How would you like the y-labels to look?

Comment: Actually probably the same, just without 1e8 and with the scale of the returns in the y axis label (i.e. Volume (millions))?

Comment: I've added a second example, using matplotlib directly. Interestingly, `sharex=True` works with the second example, but not when using the pandas DataFrame.plot calls.